# como puedo solucionar este problema: El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, .net

hola a todos buenas noches, tengo un problema tengo un formulario en windows forms que este tiene unos controles para hacer altas, bajas y cambios , tambien tiene un datagridview donde se muestran los datos de la una tabla de la base de datos que se llama "tblProveedores" que sirve para registrar proveedores , tengo un problema y me gustaria saber por que ocurre y como lo puedo solucionar y es el siguiente, puedo insertar registros y tambien se pueden editar sus datos en dado caso de que lo requiera el usuario , si yo selecciono una fila mediante el evento "GridviewProveedores_RowStateChanged" si yo selecciono una fila esta me muestra en los textbox y en un combobox los datos pero al momento de yo insertar un registro y intento seleccionar una fila me marca la excepcion de "El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección." o cuando borro una fila se puede eliminar pero quiero seleccionar otra y vuelve a marcar el mismo error por que pasa esto? adjunto imagenes y codigo

```
private void GridviewProveedores_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridviewProveedores.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (GridviewProveedores.Rows[e.Row.Index].Selected == true)
            {
                textBox1.Text = (string)GridviewProveedores.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells[1].Value;
                textBox2.Text = (string)GridviewProveedores.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells[2].Value;
                textBox3.Text = (string)GridviewProveedores.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells[3].Value;
                cboMarcas.Text = (string)GridviewProveedores.Rows[e.Row.Index].Cells[4].Value;
            }

            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si bien tengo entendido, `.Cells[ ]` es de índice cero cero, y acá empiezas por índice 1. Intenta empezando por 0 en vez de 1.

Comment: si bueno , lo que pasa es que tengo una columna oculta que viene siendo el id y me sirve para cuando se quiere hacer un update o un delete

Comment: Quizá no sea `Cells[#]`, si no `e.Row.Index`, mira si el evento que estás usando se ejecuta antes o después de agregar datos al grid